"AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null" In Python Chess Program
import chess
import chess.pgn
import chess.engine
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

# Function to get FEN position from a popup window
def get_fen_position():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    fen_position = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Paste the FEN position:")
    root.destroy()
    return fen_position

# Function to evaluate position using Stockfish
def evaluate_position(board, engine, depth_white=17, depth_black=6, multipv=3):
    if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
        result = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=depth_white))
        move = result['pv'][0]
        board.push(move)
    else:
        infos = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=depth_black), multipv=multipv)
        moves = [info['pv'][0] for info in infos if 'pv' in info]
        for move in moves:
            board.push(move)
            response = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=depth_white))
            board.pop()
    return board

# Function to recursively evaluate and write moves to PGN
def recursive_evaluation(board, engine, node, depth=1, max_depth=8, pbar=None):
    if depth > max_depth:
        return

    board = evaluate_position(board, engine)
    
    if board.turn == chess.BLACK:
        infos = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=6), multipv=3)
        for info in infos:
            if 'pv' not in info:
                continue
            new_board = board.copy()
            move = info['pv'][0]
            new_board.push(move)
            new_node = node.add_variation(move)
            recursive_evaluation(new_board, engine, new_node, depth + 1, max_depth, pbar)
    else:
        move = board.peek()
        new_node = node.add_variation(move)
        recursive_evaluation(board, engine, new_node, depth + 1, max_depth, pbar)
    
    if pbar:
        pbar.update(1)

# Main function to run the script
def main():
    # Path to Stockfish executable
    stockfish_path = 'C:/Users/Admintrator/Downloads/stockfish-windows-x86-64-avx2/stockfish/stockfish-windows-x86-64-avx2.exe'

    # Path to the existing PGN file
    pgn_path = "C:/Users/Admintrator/OneDrive - Nguyen Sieu School/Documents/EnCroissant/Nhị Cuộc Phi Đao.pgn"

    # Initialize engine
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(stockfish_path)

    # Set Stockfish options for threads and hash size
    engine.configure({"Threads": 16, "Hash": 8192})

    # Get FEN position from user
    fen = get_fen_position()

    # Load the existing PGN file
    with open(pgn_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as pgn:
        game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)

    # Set up the board with the given FEN position
    board = chess.Board(fen)
    node = game.end()

    # Initialize progress bar
    max_depth = 8
    total_steps = sum(3**i for i in range(max_depth))  # Total steps for progress bar
    with tqdm(total=total_steps, desc="Evaluating Position") as pbar:
        # Evaluate position and add moves to PGN
        recursive_evaluation(board, engine, node, max_depth=max_depth, pbar=pbar)

    # Write the updated game to the PGN file
    with open("evaluated_game.pgn", "w", encoding="utf-8") as pgn_out:
        exporter = chess.pgn.FileExporter(pgn_out)
        game.accept(exporter)
    
    # Close engine
    engine.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I wanted to make a tool that uses stockfish to automatically continue to evaluate a certain position in a .PGN file. Somehow it runs 3/4 of the way and say this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\Downloads\FEN continue.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\Downloads\FEN continue.py", line 92, in main
    game.accept(exporter)
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\pgn.py", line 883, in accept
    self.variations[0]._accept(board, visitor)
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\pgn.py", line 756, in _accept
    top.node._accept_node(parent_board, visitor)
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\pgn.py", line 733, in _accept_node
    visitor.visit_move(parent_board, self.move)
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\pgn.py", line 1403, in visit_move
    self.write_token(board.san(move) + " ")
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2866, in san
    return self._algebraic(move)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2879, in _algebraic
    san = self._algebraic_and_push(move, long=long)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2884, in _algebraic_and_push
    san = self._algebraic_without_suffix(move, long=long)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admintrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2920, in _algebraic_without_suffix
    assert piece_type, f"san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got {move} in {self.fen()}"
AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got f8b8 in r6K/p1pbqppp/2nP3n/bP6/2B1P3/1Qp2N2/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b - - 0 11

I have no idea what to fix here, tried using ChatGPT but still can't get it to work. Gone through every single same error on Stackoverflow but still can't fix it.

I have no idea about the specifics, but I'm reading the move you're trying to make simply isn't legal. Why do you think it should be?

Well, the FEN position I wanted to start with is r1bqk1nr/pppp1ppp/2n5/b7/2B1P3/1Qp2N2/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 1 8. After evaluating about 2528 valid moves in the sequence. It just randomly says error, it's not my fault, neither I wanted to make the illegal move on an illegal FEN. The move is made by the engine or there is something wrong in my code. Please help.

You have no piece on f8 as black and can therefore not move any piece from that square to b8. Please refer to the position in the fen on Lichess. The error you are seeing is due to the "move" being illegal.

Well, the FEN position I wanted to start with is r1bqk1nr/pppp1ppp/2n5/b7/2B1P3/1Qp2N2/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 1 8. After evaluating about 2528 valid moves in the sequence. It just randomly says error, it's not my fault, neither I wanted to make the illegal move on an illegal FEN. The move is made by the engine or there is something wrong in my code. Please help.

@VươngQuốcHiển can you print out what moves it makes along the way? That would probably help to narrow it down.
